# организация структуры в mongo

Tags: mongodb

Есть интернет магазин товаров, необходимо реалиpовать на mongo. 
Структура Каталог, Субкаталог и последний уровень товар.
Как правильно сделать Mongo?

1. Разделить на 3 коллекции (Каталоги, субкаталоги и товары)
2. Или

   ```
   catalog : {
       1 : {
           id: 1,
           name: "Товары для дома",
           subcatalog: {
                id: 1
                name: "Светильники,
                products: {
                    1: {
                        name: "Товар 1",
                        properies: {

                   }
               }
           }
       },
       subcatalog: {
            id: 2
            name: "Пылесосы,
            products: {
                1: {
                   name: "Товар 1",
                   properies: {

                   }
               }
           }
       },
   },
   2 : {
       id: 1,
       name: "Товары для сада",
       subcatalog: {
            id: 1
            name: "Лопаты,
            products: {
                1: {
                       name: "Товар 1",
                       properies: {

                       }
                   }
               }
           },
          subcatalog: {
                id: 2
                name: "Совки,
                products: {
                   1: {
                       name: "Товар 1",
                       properies: {

                       }
                   }
               }
           },
       }
   }
   ```

Как вообще праавильно?

Answer (score 3):

Если задание не учебное, то советую категории товаров не вкладывать друг в друга. Во-первых, если потребуется поиск, то структура с поддокументами очень усложнит задачу. Во-вторых, не стоит создавать такие структуры с учётом возможного изменения количества уровней вложенности в будущем.

Просто создайте `ParentId` в подкаталогах и опционально такие кеширующие поля как `CategoryLevel`, `ChildrenCount` в родительских категориях.
В стиле документов будет удобно хранить лишь сами товары и их характеристики, хотя, например, единицы измерения в моём проекте пришлось выносить в отдельную коллекцию.

Например:

каталоги:

```
{
    id: 1,
    name: "Товары для дома",
},
{
    id: 2,
    parentId: 1,
    name: "Светильники
},
...
```

товары:

```
{
    id: 1,
    categoryId: 2,
    name: "Товар 1",
    properies: {
        { name: 'Вес', value: 1, div: 'г'},
        ...
               }
},
...
```

Comment: а можете пример привести на примере моих данных

Comment: @ruslik гляньте обновление

Comment: ну так это получается SQL с релэйшэнами

Comment: @ruslik нуда, тут важно понять ключевую вещь, монга может хранить документ-подобные структуры и ещё она быстрая в сравнении с скл-бд, но она не так сильно отличается от последних. Например, деревья зависимых объектов это немного другое, чем документы, для таких структур даже нет нормальных способов делать запросы, максимум пару уровней вложенности и их приходится хранить как в обычной реляционной базе.

Comment: Единственный вариант когда можно хранить дерево объектов - это когда оно загружается клиенту, редактируется и выгружается обратно, без всяких запросов на поиск и особых операций над ним. Что-нибудь простое типа блокнота с системой папок для хранения записей.

Comment: Да, я понял , спасибо.

Comment: А еще вопрос  Делаю импорт файла в клиент монго. Файл json и он проходит валидацию, но импорт не осуществляется и выдает
exception: SyntaxError: Unexpected token }

Comment: @ruslik, вполне возможно, что у вас кавычки строковые не " а ', попробуйе на малом примере различные варианты, джсон парсер в монге немного строгий

Answer (score 2):

В nosql не надо думать в терминах 3-й нормальной формы SQL. В nosql должно быть удобно выбирать всевозможные данные, которые могут потребоваться. Очевидные запросы - это получить товары в группе и подгруппе, отфильтровать товары по одному или нескольким критериям в группе/подгруппе. Нет необходимости хранить описание объектов в сложной структуре, которая красиво выглядит, но с которой неудобно работать. Например, такой структуры больше чем достаточно для ситуации, описанной в вопросе.

Товары:

```
{id: 1, name: "Товар 1", categories: [1,45], color: "красный", weight: "120"},
{id: 2, name: "Товар 2", categories: [2,72], size: "45", material:"кожа"},
```

...

Категории:

```
{id: 1, name: "Стройматериалы"},
{id: 2, name: "Одежда"},
{id: 45, name: "Разноцветные тяжести", parents:[1], props:["color","weight"]},
{id: 72, name: "Одежда с размерами", parents:[2], props:["size","material"]}
```

В дальнейшем будете расширять структуру, но придерживаться принципа делать все как можно проще. Не бойтесь дублирования данных, и что база подрастет из-за этого, ничего в этом страшного нет.

Comment: Только со свойствами не согласен, их можно в properties запихнуть :) и желательно {'цвет': 'значение'} так можно разбить при помощи unwind и потом собрать все для фильтра + фильтровать тоже так будет проще

Comment: @Orange_shadow как раз в том и смысл, чтобы ничего собирать не пришлось. Документ сам по себе является единым целым, как у него внутри что хранится не принципиально. Вот когда необходимо работать с коллекцией, лишние агрегации и прочие мапинги пользы приносят мало. кроме вопросов скорости еще и встают вопросы принципиальной возможности реализации выборки. На хабре было несколько статей как зафейлили сначала sql, потом nosql, потом опять вернулись к sql...

Comment: Ну а как  будешь обход свойств делать ? если у тебя все подряд ? собрать и разобрать не так сложно и не ресурсно затратно, правда до какого то момента :)

Comment: Не вижу кейса, когда контроллер (или сразу вью) не знает какой документ (вид документа) обрабатывает, и не знает какие свойства есть в данном документе, и что еще более важно что они означают (какой у них тип как минимум и какой виджет для отображения значений будет нужен), перечисление свойств есть в категории, если так уж надо. Если это список документов, то отображаются свойства, которые захочет отобразить список, undefined->пусто; если карточка документа то для нее в любом случае будет и описание свойств (с типами и возможными значениями), и категория, и т.д.

Comment: И в таком случае никаким образом `properties:[{"цвет":"красный"},{"вес":"стопицот тонн"}]` не поможет, добавит только цикл'ов по разыменованию или `properties:{"цвет":"красный","вес":"стопицот тонн"}` ничем не будет отличаться от плоского документа.

Comment: Добавив в документ фиксированные свойства приходишь к тому, что дополнительные свойства от фиксированных не отличаются, и что весь документ состоит из дополнительных свойств. А тогда зачем дополнительные свойства отделять как-то от фиксированных? В конечном итоге они равноправны, т.к. в совокупности полностью описывают документ.

Comment: Возможно, но тогда нужно все время обновлять в группе список отображаемых свойств, и документ становится тяжелее для восприятия, особенно если у него будет пару десятков свойств, но это дело вкуса